# Upload robots.txt to the root folder failed

Tags: robots.txt

I would like to prevent robots to index my web site. I created a robots.txt file with this content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Now I must place this file in the root folder of my website. I try with my ftp software but it doesn't work. The upload failed. As you can see on the picture below, **I try at the very top level ( / ). Is it correct? Or do I have to upload the file in the /httpdocs folder?**

[image]

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

Here is the content of the httpdocs folder

[image]

Comment: where is the index file of your website?

Comment: Where is the root folder for your root application? robots.txt should be inside that.

Comment: @Robin, Amar: I updated my question to show you the content of my httpdocs folder. I don't have any index file (this is an asp.net mvc website).

Comment: @Bronzato - where is the home.asp/default.asp/index.asp file? once you locate your main website's index file that means you need to put it in there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

robots.txt should go where the root of your **website** is. It looks like you should put it in httpdocs from your screenshots.

To check...copy it there, and navigate to yoursite.com/robots.txt . If you get a 404, then it's in the wrong place. If you see your robots.txt file, you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

`httpdocs` is the root of your website.